# Alternative for if else statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The following code is working properly, however I would assume there is a more efficient way to have the logic flow. Currently I am writing out the same function twice with a subtle change in the output string. Does anyone know of way to make this logic work with less code?

```
if (result <= 1) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = Math.ceil(result) + " roll of wallpaper";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = Math.ceil(result) + " rolls of wallpaper";
}
```

Comment: Use an extra variable for the part that changes. Initialise it conditionally, then use it in the part that is common for all cases.

Comment: Wow, a lot of same answer to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the difference beforehand and add it in manually:

```
var s = ( result <= 1 ? 's' : '' );
document.getElementById('output').innerText = 
    Math.ceil(result) + " roll" +s+ " of wallpaper";
```

Edit: Cutting-edge JS bonus, using template strings is extra fun (need babel):

```
var displayResult = Math.ceil(result);
var s = ( result <= 1 ? 's' : '' );
document.getElementByid('output').innerText = 
    `${displayResult} roll${s} of wallpaper`;
```

Comment: No problem.  Please make sure to mark the one you ended up using as the solution for other users.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('output').innerText = [
                                Math.ceil(result),
                                ' roll',
                                result > 1 ? 's' : '',
                                ' of wallpaper'].join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be:

```
var s = (result <= 1) ? 's' : '';
document.getElementById('output').innerText = Math.ceil(result) + ' roll'+s+' of wallpaper';
```